# swift: UIPageViewController action

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UIPageViewController` and this code to flip my pages :

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? { 
        let contentVC = viewController as! ContentViewController
        if contentVC.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getContentViewController(withIndex: contentVC.itemIndex - 1) 
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let contentVC = viewController as! ContentViewController
        if contentVC.itemIndex + 1 < images.count {
            return getContentViewController(withIndex: contentVC.itemIndex + 1)
        }

        return nil
    }
```

But I want to flip pages on button press. I should call `viewControllerBefore` and `viewControllerAfter` in my button action? Or I should write another code? How to do it?

**Update**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createPageViewController()
        setupPageControll()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func createPageViewController() {
        let pageController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
        pageController.dataSource = self
        pageController.delegate = self

        if images.count > 0{
            let firstController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 0)!
            let contentControllers = [firstController]

            pageController.setViewControllers(contentControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        pageViewController = pageController

        self.addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
        self.view.insertSubview(pageViewController!.view, at: 0)
        pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    }

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func setupPageControll(){
        let apperance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        apperance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        apperance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        apperance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    func currentControllerIndex() -> Int{
        let pageItemController = self.currentConroller()

        if let controller = pageItemController as? ContentViewController {
            return controller.itemIndex
        }
        return -1
    }

    func currentConroller() -> UIViewController?{
        if (self.pageViewController?.viewControllers?.count)! > 0{
            return self.pageViewController?.viewControllers![0]
        }

        return nil
    }

    func getContentViewController(withIndex index: Int) -> ContentViewController? {
        if index < images.count{
            let contentVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController
            contentVC.itemIndex = index
            contentVC.imageName = images[index]

            return contentVC
        }

        return nil
    }

}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        pendingIndex = (pendingViewControllers.first as! ContentViewController).itemIndex
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if completed {
            let currentIndex = pendingIndex
            if let index = currentIndex {
                self.PageControl.currentPage = index
            }

        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let contentVC = viewController as! ContentViewController
        if contentVC.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getContentViewController(withIndex: contentVC.itemIndex - 1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let contentVC = viewController as! ContentViewController
        if contentVC.itemIndex + 1 < images.count {
            return getContentViewController(withIndex: contentVC.itemIndex + 1)
        }

        return nil
    }
```

**New Update**

new:

```
@IBAction func nextAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let pageController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
        pageController.dataSource = self
        pageController.delegate = self

        let secondController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 1)!
        let contentControllers = [secondController]

        pageController.setViewControllers(contentControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        pageViewController = pageController
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this instance method

> setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, 
>                 direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection, 
>                  animated: Bool, 
>                completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)

Like this

```
// self is of type UIPageViewController
self.setViewControllers([vc],direction:.forward,animated:true) { _ in
}
```

Comment: If I have one controller `[vc]` then the application crashes `'The number of provided view controllers (1) doesn't match the number required (2) for the requested spine location (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid)'` I add example of code in question. Under **New Update** title. Could you say what I do wrong?

Comment: I have same problem of use `pageController.setViewControllers([contentControllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Have you looked at my code? What's wrong with code?

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func nextPageBtnPressed_TouchupInside(_ sender : UIButton ) {
    if let pageViewController = self.parent as? PageViewController {
        pageViewController.goToNextPage()
        pageViewController.changeCurrentPageIndicator(pageViewController: pageViewController)
    }
}


func goToNextPage(animated: Bool = true, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
    if let currentViewController = viewControllers?[0] {
        if let nextPage = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) {
            setViewControllers([nextPage], direction: .forward, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }
    }


func changeCurrentPageIndicator(pageViewController : DTCPageViewController) {
    pageViewController.view.clipsToBounds = false
    pageViewController.view.sizeToFit()
    let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]
    currentIndex = orderViewController.index(of: pageContentViewController)!
    self.pageControl.currentPage = orderViewController.index(of: pageContentViewController)!
}
```

write goToNextPage() and changeCurrentPageIndicator() ------
 In PageViewControllerClass
 Or make extension
extension PageViewController

Comment: I have many issues. What is `dataSource?` where I should take it?

Comment: The datasource is UIPageViewControllerDataSource. In which viewController you implemented pageviewcontroller implemetation.  suppose PageViewController : UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate

Comment: I write the code before `pageController.dataSource = self` and if I delete dataSource? from `dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController)` I have error Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIPageVie

Comment: have you implementing above logic in pageviewcontroller

Comment: which functionality you want do in app?? can you tell me?

Comment: I want to flip my page next on button click. Like in `func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?`

Comment: If you want to flip your page on button click then it's not possible with delegate method of pageviewcontroller. See my code.. In that goToNextBtnPressed

Comment: I get `Use of unresolved identifier 'dataSource'` where I should declare it?